# Probability of each player withdrawing 4 aces given 3 cards each on a 40 card deck?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Let's say there is a deck of 40 cards with 4 aces (just take any 12 non-ace cards of a regular deck for instance)

We deal three cards for each player (so 40-12=24 remain undealt)
what is the probability of exactly each player having one ace?

I was thinking that a player has $\frac{4}{40}$ chance of having one ace on the 1st card then the second player has $\frac{3}{39}$ and so on, totalizing $\frac{4!}{39! - 35!}$, but this doesn't work because I just calculated the possibility of each player getting an ace on the 1st card dealt. It could also be that player 1 gets not an ace on the first card dealt but an ace on the second (remember that each player gets 3 cards)

So should I take into account the way the cards are dealt as well? Because for instance concerning the 1st two cards: say the first is an ace for player 1 $\frac{4}{40}$ then the chance of the second being an ace for player 2 is $\frac{3}{39}$. But if the player 1 first card was not an ace, that probability is changed to $\frac{4}{39}$, since there are still 4 aces left on the deck...
How could I take all the possibilities in consideration then? Sounds like a pretty boring task since there are $12 \choose 2$ possible configurations, considering the ways the 12 cards are deal to each player... Is there a better way to compute this probability?

Comment: NB: $40-12= 28$

Answer (score 1):

The first player gets exactly one ace with probability $\dfrac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{36}{2}}{\binom{40}{3}}$ seen by picking which ace followed by picking which two other non-ace cards are used compared to the total number of three-card hands possible.

*Given that* the first player received exactly one ace, the probability that the second player then receives exactly one ace given what cards remain in the deck occurs with probability $\dfrac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{34}{2}}{\binom{37}{3}}$

Applying multiplication principle, the probability then that both the first and second player receive exactly one ace is $\dfrac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{36}{2}}{\binom{40}{3}}\times\dfrac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{34}{2}}{\binom{37}{3}}$

Continuing in this fashion you get one representation for the probability that every player receives exactly one ace as:

$$\frac{4!\binom{36}{2}\binom{34}{2}\binom{32}{2}\binom{30}{2}}{\binom{40}{3}\binom{37}{3}\binom{34}{3}\binom{31}{3}}$$

Comment: Note: "We deal *three* cards to each player" ...

Comment: Good catch.  I'll correct once trick or treaters are done and I go upstairs